# Why flex columns have not the same height in Safari, but Chome is well?

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I have 2 cols inside the flex wrapper. This cols have display:flex also. Inside column the div with minh100vh and h100%. When I test this code in Chrome, Firefox and even IE, I see the columns with the same height and inner div streched for all column's height. But when I open Safari in Mac or Ipad, this structure breaks down, because my columns have only min height 100vh.

link:[example link](http://ct93058-joomla-2.tw1.ru/cafe/)

img:[image: example screen]

```
    body {
       height: 100%;
       ...
    }    
    .container {
        display: flex;
        min-height: 100vh;
        height: 100%;
        ...
    }
    .col {
        display: flex;
        min-height: 100vh;
        ...
    }

    div {
        min-height: 100vh;
        height: 100%;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest** code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: You link doesn't work. I had similar issue for my Safari. Make sure you don't have flex: 1 1 0%. i.e. make sure flex-basis is auto